# Display block issue in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, block

I'm working on a website for a client and I have 3 boxes that go across horizontally near the bottom of the home page. Reading New Sermons, Tidbits, and Prayer Requests. For some reason the text that I have spanning across the boxes(images) does not want to follow my property and rule of the display:block. I've tried the `\9` and the `*display:block;` to see if those work but it's not. Any other suggestions?

The website is http://lordjesuschurchofgod.com

Here is the code that is giving me trouble

```
body.home .notices .title {                                     
    position: relative;
    top: -85px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Rather than posting your website address, you should add the code that of the page that is causing trouble in your question.

Comment: I assume you haven’t done any cross-browser testing on this so far? Because in every other browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) I get the same messed up view of these three boxes that I get in IE 8 – _only_ IE 9/10 seem to display this as you want it too … so I’d say IE 9/10 displaying it the way you want is rather a matter of luck than of you doing it actually _right_. (And btw., who comes up with domain names like that? To me that domain reads “Lord Jesusch Urch of God” at first glance …)

Comment: @CBroe: its the client choice. not mine. No need to harp on the url name. And you must have been looking at it when I was trying to test some things I saw online.

Comment: @Schleis the code is up

Comment: New version of IE renders few tags in a different way. I encountered same problem while adding `display` property to the `DropDownList` element. For few `tags` IE won't add closing `tag`. So the display property won't work if there is no closing tag. You can see this by viewing rendered page source.

Comment: Hrm, you were changing things while we were looking at it? That means we were looking at a moving target. The source could be different after every refresh. This is not a good idea. Can you make a page that stays as it is? For instance on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)..

Comment: Anyway, maybe it's a better idea to use the pictures as background images for the links, rather than separate elements.

Comment: @MrLister source hasnt been changed for the last 12 hours. So your good. And it wont be changed until I figure out the problem :)

Comment: @Bharadwaj do you have another suggestion of doing it than?

Comment: I decided to go with the the pictures as background images for the links and just working with that